# Ethernet connection with RTL8111/8168/8411 not working anymore

Tags: dual-boot, ethernet, disconnect

My problem seems to be a frequent one but I think that I tried all the sparse solutions that I might have found on other posts but without any success so I hope that you may help me.

### Issue explanation

I have a dual boot linux/win10 on my laptop and I started experimenting issues with ethernet connection, first on win10 and then on linux, a few times ago but things were getting fixed by restarting network-manager under linux or reinstalling drivers under win10.
Nonetheless at that precise moment I have no more ethernet connection at all on both platforms, the ethernet cable is said to be disconnected and the link is not detected.

### Commands to understand the issue

`lspci | grep -i realtek`

> > `02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
> >     02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)`

`lsmod | grep r816`

> > `r8168                 499712  0`

`dmesg | grep r816`

> > `[   14.114832] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
> >     [   14.114838] r8169 0000:02:00.1: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
> >     [   14.118523] r8169 0000:02:00.1 eth0: RTL8411 at 0xffffa42300da5000, 2c:56:dc:37:4c:2d, XID 1c800800 IRQ 52
> >     [   14.118524] r8169 0000:02:00.1 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
> >     [   17.717539] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: renamed from eth0
> >     [   42.961609] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [   42.961611] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [   61.733562] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [   61.816487] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [   80.523534] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [   80.607153] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [   99.402597] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [   99.485792] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [  118.043226] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [  118.126551] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [  136.770237] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [  136.853215] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [  155.872182] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [  155.955298] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [  174.853471] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [  174.936759] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [  193.918635] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [  194.002364] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
> >     [  212.622095] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link up
> >     [  212.705764] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down`

`sudo ethtool enp2s0f1`

> > `Settings for enp2s0f1:
> >         Supported ports: [ TP ]
> >         Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
> >                                 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
> >                                 1000baseT/Full 
> >         Supported pause frame use: No
> >         Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
> >         Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
> >                                 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
> >                                 1000baseT/Full 
> >         Advertised pause frame use: No
> >         Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
> >         Speed: 100Mb/s
> >         Duplex: Half
> >         Port: Twisted Pair
> >         PHYAD: 0
> >         Transceiver: internal
> >         Auto-negotiation: on
> >         MDI-X: Unknown
> >         Supports Wake-on: pumbg
> >         Wake-on: d
> >         Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
> >                        drv probe ifdown ifup
> >         Link detected: no`

### What I tried to do to solve the issue

- I tried to reboot multiple times on both OS and to restart multiple times network-manager but in vain. At some moments I had my ethernet connection working for a few minutes but the frequency of these events is decreasing since the first occurence of the issue.
- I tried to install r8168 driver from Realtek website instead of r8169 but that doesn't work
- I tried to change some parameters like `autoneg` or `duplex` with `ethtool` for no result
- I tried to let my laptop go completely out of power and then restarted it but that made no change

At that point I am a bit stuck and I don't have much idea of what to do to fix the problem. Maybe that some of you will have ideas or solutions and I thank you in advance for paying attention to my message. Of course I stay available if you need more precisions.

Comment: sounds to me like the card is failing

Comment: The proper Ubuntu driver for this card would be `r8168-dkms`. Regarding the link, please describe your network cable configuration. Where does the cable from the computer go... switch/hub/modem/other? Ping me at `@heynnema`.

Comment: @heynnema : I just installed `r8168-dkms`. The only modification that I can see is in dmesg where my ethernet interface reamains as `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0f1: link is not ready`. About the network configuration, that issue occured at 2 different places with different cables and networks but I'm not in charge of these networks so I don't know if the connections are made with switch/hub or anything.

Comment: What about your network where this is normally connected? Are you using CAT5 or better cables? For IPv6, try setting it to "ignore" in the Network panel GUI.

Comment: @heynnema My ethernet cables are CAT5E. I don't have access to the network that I usually connect to because I am abroad but things were fine with those networks in the beginning and I use wifi at home. I disabled ipv6 but with no result.